# Read a text file and shows the contents in different text boxes?

Tags: vb.net, file-io

What i'm trying to do is: read a text file from a WebServer, get the content and shows in a display with separated text boxes...

How can i do it?

The file is: `http://www.gruma.ufsm.br/gruma/cmsm/cmsm_2013110812.txt`

And the content is: Date, Wind speed and Acumulated Rain

```
      Public Function GetPage(ByVal PageURL As String) As String
    Dim S As String = ""
    Try
        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(PageURL)
        Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
        Using Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
            S = Reader.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("FAIL: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return S
End Function
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or what specifically are you having problems with, getting the file, etc....

Comment: Once you have the file content you will need to get the relevant parts of the file you need for each textbox. Using regular expressions or good old fashioned index of functions. Based on the format of the file, split each line by a semi colon, the first part is the date, second is wind speed, third is accumulated rain.

Comment: Why seperate textboxes? can it be on a single container (ie listbox, datagridview) instead?

Comment: personally, I'd read it line by line (`streamreader.readline`) then split each string at the ";" to get the distinct elements,  might need a lot of textboxes, a datagridview might work better

Comment: Mark, i'm not gettin any erros, its just i dont know how to separate de the content to show them in diferent boxes.

Comment: andrewb, i'll try it.

Comment: Malky i need in separate boxes 'cause after im gonna do a display showing to users... but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Plutonix can you make a code for me based on this? im a newer programmer and i'm not sure if i can do it D:

Comment: Btw, thanks for all you guys, who helping me and sorry for my bad english x.x

Comment: Note: This is a sample input record: 21Z08NOV2013; 1.5; 1.3. The first column is prefixed with a string '21Z' that is not part of the date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `list` `all` the `lines` and `extrat` from `each` `line` `Date` , `WindSpeed`, `RAin` :

```
    Dim postrequ As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.gruma.ufsm.br/gruma/cmsm/cmsm_2013110812.txt"), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim responsea As HttpWebResponse
    responsea = DirectCast(postrequ.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(responsea.GetResponseStream())
    Dim line As String = postreqreader.ReadLine

    While (Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)))
        Dim mydate, windspeed, AcumulatedRain As String 'DAte , Wind,Rain 
        windspeed = line.ToString.Split(";")(1) 'Output : WInd Speed 
        AcumulatedRain = line.ToString.Split(";")(2) 'Output : Rain Acumulation
        mydate = line.ToString.Substring(0, line.ToString.IndexOf(";")) 'Output : DATE
        line = postreqreader.ReadLine
    End While
```

if you want to check for the current `date NOW() Today()` the formatted date on your text file is not valid date you can not `Parse` it and `compare` it ....

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
    ' Get web response, I am just using a text file for brevity...
    ' Sample data: 22/11/2013;10k;100mm
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.txt")
    Dim line As String

    Do
        line = reader.ReadLine ' read each line of text file

        ' In Do...Until so check line is not nothing
        If line IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim parts As String() = line.Split(New Char() {";"})
            ' parts(0) = date, parts(1) = wind, parts(2) = rain
        End If

    Loop Until a Is Nothing

    reader.Close()
```

Comment: the file should be downloaded